# Lucky Controller is not working , Code is looking Correct

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I am facing the Error while running the code , attached is the Error and Code , that's not working.
Thank's in Advance

> Exception thrown when handling an exception 
>       (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: 
>       [Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position 7 in method AppBundle\Controller\LuckyController::numberAction() in C:\xampp\php\hamad\src\AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\php\hamad/app/config\routing.yml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.)

Code:

```
//src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     *@Route('lucky/number')
     */
     public function numberAction()
     {
         $number = random_int(0, 100);

         return new Response(
             '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
         );
     }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time and reformat your question, especially use code tag properly. Anyway your `@Route(...)` annotation is invalid.

Comment: Sure @emix Kindly i have reformatted the Question, kindly remove the vote Down, any how your comment solved my problem regarding the Annotations yes it was invalid. Kindly post your comment as answer to accept. Thank You

Comment: This doesn't look too well. This time I'll do it for you, but please don't be lazy next time asking a question. Have you tried with `@Route(path="/lucky/number")` ? Did you clear the cache? Do you have `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` installed?

Comment: @emix I have posted the answer, the previous and the current change in Route.Thanks for Sincere interest and response, next time will be definitely careful. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have used

```
/**
     *@Route('lucky/number')
     */
```

While the Accurate Format is

```
  /**
 * @Route("/lucky/number")
 */
```

Solved